# Bootstrap 3 - How can I put the left and right borders of the image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Such a situation, there are 3 pictures.

**I have:**

1) left.png - left border for div.

2) right.png - right border for the div.

3) background.png - background for div.

**I have a code:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-lg-4 column left_part"> ... content ... </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Task**
There is "div", which should has its own background (background.png), the left border with a fixed width and the right border with a fixed width. The left border - left.png, right border - right.png. How to do this using the bootstrap 3?

Structure of DIV: http://i60.tinypic.com/29boxsl.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean. The borders are images? So you have three columns : L (skinny column), middle (this has a background, R (skinny column)? This is done with CSS, not particularly with Bootstrap because there is no design pattern like this, though you could over-ride their column classes, making it more annoying than just doing it with custom CSS.

[image]

#### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/jigeku/1/edit

**HTML**

```
<div class="my-funky-img-box">
   <div class="col-bdr left-border-col">
   </div>
   <!--/.col-bdr.left-border-col-->
   <div class="background-col">
   </div>
   <!--/.background-col-->
   <div class="col-bdr right-border-col">
   </div>
   <!--/.col-bdr.left-border-col-->
</div>
<!--/.my-funky-img-box-->
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%
}
.my-funky-img-box {
    background: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    height:40%; /* this is the height  */
}
.col-bdr,
.background-col {
    display: table-cell
}
.left-border-col {
    width: 15px;
    background: blue; /* put a background image here */
}
.right-border-col {
    width: 15px;
    background: purple; /* put a background image here */
}
.background-col {
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/500/500);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}

/* PUT THIS INSIDE A MEDIA QUERY IF YOU DON'T WANT ALL VIEWPORT WIDTHS TO SEE IT */
```

Comment: Thanks! I did it. But another way. In your method, when I insert instead left border color -> left border image for example, and my div will be 700px height, then original image will be very expanded.